# An embeded form in a table and ajax not working properly

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem with a form that is inside a table. On its own on it works as it should, posting the values. But I am trying to use ajax to catch the form data. I can only get it to catch the first element. I just don't know if this is even possible

```js
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {
  var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};

  // Testing 
  console.log(that);
  console.log(url);
  console.log(type);
  console.log(data);
  console.log(name);

  that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
    var that = $(this),
      name = that.attr('name'),
      id = that.attr('id'),
      value = that.val();
    data[name] = value;
    console.log(name);
    console.log(value);
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {}

  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<form id="form1" method="post" action="post.php" class="ajax">
  <input name="id_1" value="1" />
</form>
</td>
<td>
  <input form="form1" type="text" name="record_1" value="Scooby Doo" />
</td>
```

Comment: share the code you written

Comment: <tr>
        <td><form id="form1" method="post" action="post.php" class="ajax"><input name="id_1" value="1"/></form></td>
        <td><input form="form1" type="text" name="record_1" value="Scooby Doo" /></td>
        <td><input form="form1" type="submit" value="Save" /></td>
    </tr>

Comment: `I can only get it to catch the first element`, your element `record_1` is not inside your `form`, wrap the `form` around the whole table to include all form elements

Comment: @empiric — The code implies that each row will be a form of its own. Wrapping the form around the whole table would wrap *extra* inputs in it.

Answer (score 1):

## The problem

> ```
> that.find('[name]')
> ```

The jQuery `find` method finds matching elements that descend from the element you are searching from.

It won't find form controls which *belong* to the form but are not *inside* it.

Like this one:

> ```
> <input form="form1" type="text" name="record_1" value="Scooby Doo" >
> ```

… which is outside the form element but associated with it via the `form` *attribute*.

---

## Fixing your approach

You need to combine the fields *in* the form with the fields that *belong* to the form.

The generic way to do this is to find the fields with `form` attributes which match the form's `id` and combine them with the ones you already have.

```
var that = $(this); 
var fields_in_that = that.find("[name]");
var form_id = that.attr("id");
var fields_belonging_to_that = $(`[form="${form_id}"]`);
var all_fields = fields_in_that.add(fields_belonging_to_that);
```

You could instead assume that all the inputs in the *table row* are the inputs you want.

```
var that = $(this); 
var row = that.parents("tr"); // Likely to break if you nest tables. Don't nest tables.
var inputs = row.find("[name]");
```

---

## Probably a better approach

You could also forget about gathering all the data for the form fields manually and just let the browser do it for you:

```
  var data = new FormData(this); // "this" is still the form object
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data,
    contentType: false, // These two lines stop jQuery for trying to be
    processData: false, // clever with FormData and breaking it
    success: function(response) {}
  });
```

Comment: @Casperdoog2 — None of the three approaches worked?! What happened when you tried? What, specifically, didn't work about them?

Comment: The first one I get this in the console

Comment: 0: <input name="record_0" value="1">
​
1: <input form="form1" type="text" name="record_1" value="Name 1">
​
2: <input form="form1" type="text" name="record_2" value="Address 2">
​
3: <input form="form1" type="submit" value="Save">
​
context: <form id="form1" class="ajax" method="post" action="post.php" name="form_1">
​
length: 4

Comment: but i dont know how to get it to the post

Comment: @Casperdoog2 — The same way you did in the first place: `that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {` etc etc etc.

Comment: Thank you for your input on this much appreciated. But i am still not getting it. Used the first  example and I still get only one element back. It seems like I am declaring vars but not doing anything with them.

Comment: @Casperdoog2 — I thought it was obvious that you'd need to replace `that.find('[name]').each` with `all_fields.each`

Comment: Thanks you very much. I was putting all_fields in the brackets which only returned the single result. Oh well I can stop brick walling now. Thanks again you're a star

Answer (score -1):

probably this is what you want , merge element in the form and elements with attribute form equal the form id

```
$.merge(that.find('[name]'),$.find("[name][form="+that[0].id+"]"))
```

or

```
that.find('[name]').add($.find("[name][form="+that[0].id+"]"))
```

Comment: That would get *all* inputs with a name attribute (which will be most, if not all of them) not matter what form they belong to. The code implies that each row in the table has its own form, so that would get a lot of inputs that should not be included.

Comment: Do you meat that you only want get element in the  form and  record_1 in then same tr?

Comment: $.merge(that.find('[name]'),$.find("[name][form="+that[0].id+"]"))

Comment: probably this is what you want , merge element in the form and elements with attribute form equal the form id

Comment: Yes I want to get all elements in the form but not all forms

Comment: What should the whole function look like I cant seem to get anything to work

Comment: You can read Quentin's answer. It's very clear. [that.find('[name]').each...]  in your code changes to  [that.find('[name]').add($.find("[name][form="+that[0].id+"]")).each...]